# How to make my own template activity like the one prebuild in android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

How an I make my own template activity like those prebuid in Android studio…and add my own on that Android activity creation page?

I have choosen navigation drawer activity..
 For my project I have edited the fab button etc...
But the problem is that I want 200 same layout activities with my options 
Is there anyway I can load my own in the add activity option 
Or
I have to edit the same for 200 times. ?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score -1):

An [Android Library](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html) will do what you want.

Inside Android Studio go to `File` > `New` > `New Module` > `Android Library` and follow the prompts in the Wizard.

If you need to do more than the basics with it, I suggest [this tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Building-your-own-Android-library) which goes more in depth.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14880383)

Comment: Making an Android Library is the answer.